# Give a formula in terms of k for the solution to the system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If I was to have two equations:

2kx + 2y = 2

18x + 2ky = 3

And the questions asks for a condition on k that will make the system have a unique solution. I would use properties of determinants to find when k =/= 0. However, after I did that, the question asks me to give a formula in terms of k for the solution to the system, how would I go about finding that? I thought about row reducing but it would not include the fact that k =/= 0 because then the system would not stand. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

from the first equation we get
$$y=1-kx$$ plugging this in the second equation
$$18x+2k-2k^2x=3$$
$$x(18-2k^2)=3-2k$$
if $$k=\pm 3$$ we get no solutions, thus 
$$x=\frac{3-2k}{18-2k^2}$$ and $$k\ne \pm 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Well this system has two variables and two equations. The system will always have a unique solution provided that the two equations are linearly independent. This is clear when you look at the relationship between matrices and linear maps.

So we will be done once we find the values of $k$ such that this system is linearly dependent. This is easy. Consider the equation

$$\begin{vmatrix}
    2k   &    2\\
    18      & 2k \\ 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$$ $$4k^2 - 36 = 0 \Leftrightarrow k= \pm 3$$

So the equations are linearly dependent if $k=\pm 3$. In any other case, there must be a unique solution.

You may ask why we didn't need to consider the RHS of our system when finding the determinant. This is because they are just constant. If $2kx+2y$ is a linear combination of $18x+2ky$, then in any case, you'll be able to get the RHS from both equations.